# SQL - Multiplying 2 values from 2 tables to display a new table the results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue to display the specific results in SQL when trying to multiply between one table that consists of quantity and other tables that consist of price.

I think the image and the code will help you understand my issue better.

[Image attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKLn1.png)

So I have 6 customer orders (co_ID) and in each customer order, the customer has purchased products.
I am trying to multiply the quantity of each product (from customer order details table) to the relevant price (from product table),
then to finally display a new table that consists of the customer order ID and the total price of that order.

You can see that I am currently getting a different result (in the image to the left of the code).

**Customer order details table:**

```
+---------+--------+--------------+
| co_ID   | p_ID   | cod_quantity |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000001 | 150009 |233           |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000002 | 150001 | 400          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000002 | 150002 | 1000         |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000002 | 150003 | 300          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000002 | 150004 | 600          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000002 | 150008 | 2000         |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000003 | 150004 | 350          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000003 | 150005 | 500          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000003 | 150007 | 800          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000003 | 150008 | 1000         |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000004 | 150001 | 450          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000004 | 150002 | 800          |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 1000004 | 150005 | 700          |
```

**Customer Order table**

```
╔═════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ co_ID   ║ c_ID   ║ co_date             ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1000001 ║ 200001 ║ 2020-07-19 12:35:28 ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1000002 ║ 200002 ║ 2020-07-19 14:53:14 ║
╠═════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 1000003 ║ 200003 ║ 2020-07-19 09:12:40 ║
```

**The code is:**

```
SELECT factory.customer_order.co_ID, factory.customer_order_details.cod_quantity * factory.product.p_price
AS total_price
FROM factory.customer_order_details, factory.product, factory.customer_order
WHERE factory.customer_order_details.co_id = factory.customer_order.co_id;
```

I would appreciate any help, in this case, I am trying to figure this out for a while now.

FYI - I would save the total price as a column as well on the table of Customer Order (the right one with the dates) but I need to have it normalized (BCNF) and I think it wouldn't be normalized with the price in it.

Comment: hi, is it better now?

Comment: No. I refer you again to my previous comment. The linked answer is quite specific.

Comment: You need a joining condition for `factory.product`. Otherwise you're going to generate a row for every product, not just the products in the order.

Comment: If you learn to use ANSI JOIN syntax, you won't make this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a joining condition between `customer_order_details` and `product` so you multiply by the correct product price.

And to get the total for each order, you need to use the `SUM()` aggregation function and `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT co.co_ID, SUM(cod.cod_quantity * p.p_price) AS total_price
FROM customer_order AS co
JOIN customer_order_details as cod ON cod.co_id = co.co_id
JOIN product AS p ON p.p_id = cod.p_id
GROUP BY co.co_ID
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Barmar,

I need to practice more about the JOIN syntax.

I tried implementing what you wrote and I receive an error code 1054: unknown column

factory.customer_order.co_ID in 'field list' even though it is defined and I don't have typos. do you have any idea what cause this?

Comment: If you assign aliases to the table in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses, you can't use the full table name in the `SELECT` list. You have to write `co.co_ID`, not `factory.customer_order.co_ID`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar you really helped me a lot here!!!
Have a great day my friend